# Django-Rest - How to create URL & View to extract "GET" query parameters in different formats?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, get

I have an application that is sending a `GET` request in the form of `/myapi/details/?id="myid"`.

Currently my Django-Rest server is setup to receive requests as follows:

***urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('/details/<str:id>/', views.details.as_view()),
]
```

***views.py***

```
class details(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id):
        //id contains the data
```

This works fine when sending a `GET` request as `/myapi/details/"myid"`. To try and also receive requests with `/?id="myid"` I added `path('/details/?id=<str:id>/', views.details.as_view()),` to `urlpatterns`, but sending the request still hits the other URL regardless of the order.

What would be the correct way to go about this? Ideally, I would like to accept both `/"myid"` and `/?id=<str:id>` formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not how you should be using query parameters.

Couple of things that would help you understand why Django (and many other frameworks) treat query parameters this way:

1. You should use path parameters to uniquely identify resources. e.g:
   `/details/<str: id>` can return a unique Detail object having the specified `id`
2. You should use query parameters to make some query to the response that the path parameters return. For example, suppose `/details/<str: id>` returns a list. Then, `/details/103?page=1&page_size=20` can return only the first 20 items in the list of details having the id 103.

Therefore, you can only specify path parameters in Django urlpatterns.

Django stores the query parameters inside a QueryDict object (`request.GET` or `request.query_params`). You can use that to access the query parameters from the same view function as below:

```py
class details(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id):
        page = request.GET.get('page', None)
        if page:
            # filter results based on the query parameter
        else:
            # return default results
```

Here, I am using a query parameter called `page` which is a more realistic use case.

Comment: Ok I see, so anything after and including `?` is not matched in the URL pattern ? But is accessible via the query params dict.

Comment: That's right. It makes sense because query params have an entirely different use case which i tried to explain.Maybe i didnt do a good job explaining that sorry, but look up some example apis and you will get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between passing [`captured values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#example) via URL dispatcher and a [`query param`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params). You do not need to setup the URL path for query params.

A simple example:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('details/<str:id>/', details.as_view(), name='detail_view'),
]
```

views.py

```py
class details(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id):
        id_query_param = request.query_params.get('id')
        captured_value = id
        
        return Response(
            {
                'query_param': id_query_param,
                'url_dispatcher': captured_value
            }
        )
```

The endpoint accepts both URLs:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/details/1/?id=myid
and
http://localhost:8000/api/details/1/
```

Comment: So `path('details/', details.as_view(), name='detail_view')` would match the URL http://localhost:8000/api/details/?id=myid, correct ?

Comment: No, it matches `http://localhost:8000/api/details/` and `?id=myid` is a query param. Meaning that the `param` can be something else entirely like `?other=value`, you would just have to retrieve it `request.query_params.get('other')`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant.